# Changing color for fillText() on HTML5 <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to change the color for each line of my messages on canvas, but no success so far. I have tried creating variable for each one of them, but still no luck. any help would be appreciated.

```
function initiate(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas = elem.getContext("2d");
    addEventListener("mousemove", animation);

    canvas.shadowColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
    canvas.shadowOffsetX = 4;
    canvas.shadowOffsetY = 4;
    canvas.shadowBlur = 5;

    canvas.font = "bold 24px verdana, sans-serif ";
    var welcomeMessage ="Welcome to the store!";
    canvas.textAlign = "start";
    canvas.textBaseline = "bottom";
    canvas.fillText(welcomeMessage, 400, 50);

    canvas.font = "bold 14px verdana, sans-serif";
    var message2 = "Your favorite store for videos games and latest DVDs!"; 
    canvas.textAlign = "start";
    canvas.textBaseline = "bottom";
    canvas.fillText(message2, 400, 100);

    canvas.font = "bold 12px verdana, sans-serif";
    canvas.textAlign = "start";
    canvas.textBaseline = "bottom";
    // Create gradient
    //var gradient=canvas.createLinearGradient(0,0,c.width,0);
    //gradient.addColorStop("0","magenta");
    //gradient.addColorStop("0.5","blue");
    //gradient.addColorStop("1.0","red");
    //canvas.fillStyle = gradient;
    canvas.fillText(" <-- Move your mouse aroud to interact with Macroplay smily!", 400, 250);


}
```

Answer (score 72):

you have to set the color for the text.

Something like this:

```js
const canvasObj = document.getElementById('canvas')
const context = canvasObj.getContext('2d')

context.font = "bold 24px verdana, sans-serif ";
var welcomeMessage = "Welcome to the store!";
context.textAlign = "start";
context.textBaseline = "bottom";
context.fillStyle = "#ff0000"; //<======= here
context.fillText(welcomeMessage, 10, 50);

context.font = "bold 14px verdana, sans-serif";
var message2 = "Your favorite store for videos games and latest DVDs!";
context.textAlign = "start";
context.textBaseline = "bottom";
context.fillStyle = "#00ff00"; //<======= and here
context.fillText(message2, 10, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
```

Also, it could be a good idea to name your context variable "context" or "cxt" instead of "canvas". It would be less confusing :)

Comment: Agree that the name is confusing. To be precise, MDN uses "ctx" for Context2D.

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried simple fillStyles like:

```
  canvas.fillStyle = "#ff00ff";
```

The text rendering on `<canvas>` might not support advanced fill styles.

Just set new fillStyle before rendering each message.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
canvas.fillStyle = "steelblue";
```